# I need a word to convey the meaning of getting a course approved w/o ever going to class

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, idiom-requests

I've recently started working at the International Office at my University and I've found myself in need of an English word for succeeding in a test and getting a course approved without going to class at all. In Spanish it would be "rendir libre" for you bilinguals out there.
Thank you in advance!
This is my first post here btw, I hope I followed your rules neatly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, you'd say that you "placed out" of a class. That means you get credit for it without having taken it, and it implies that you took some kind of placement exam or assessment test that demonstrated that you had sufficiently learned the course material.

From The Free Dictionary:

> [Place out of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/place+out+of)
>
> To qualify for a waiver of some requirement or prerequisite: If you've placed out of introductory biology, you can take an advanced course. The school has a language requirement, but since I know Spanish, I placed out.

Comment: Or "proficiencied out".

Comment: @KristinaLopez I've never heard this, though I have heard the term "proficiency test".

Comment: "Place out" is an appropriate term, but I take issue with your claim that it means you get credit for the thing you've placed out of.  Your definition does not support that, and it is my personal experience with U.S. higher education in particular that placing out of a course does not necessarily mean that credit is awarded for that course -- it may just mean that you are permitted to start with a more advanced course.

Comment: @pellmel you're right. I was thinking of credit like qualified not credit like academic credit.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, on this page from the University of Illinois website where they discuss proficiency exams, they use "proficiency out" to describe the process of testing out of a class: http://cte.illinois.edu/testing/pnp/proficiency/dept.html